# Oracle Apex 5 Modal Call

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I created 2 interactive reports to work as a master detail. In the master, I have a link that will refresh the detail report with records for the master.

I have a create detail record button that will call a page as a modal window and then save. Everything works correctly except the Create detail button does not refresh with the master record id. The button is suppose to set the page item on the modal for the master record id.

It looks like the button is built when the original page is built and never changes. I have a dynamic action that sets an item on the main with the master record ID and I assumed that the button would use that, but it never refreshes with it.

How do I get the button to refresh when I change the item that holds the master record id? I can try and build it other ways but the I can not get the checksum to work and it will throw an error when the modal opens.

Here is the javascript call attached to the onclick of the button:

```
apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=810:6010:14381566697413::NO::P6010_TRACK_SERNO,P6010_FORM_ACTION:90,CREATE\u0026p_dialog_cs=z9T5rK-dt186xh83jq4Dy4d2vumFtU_Fj1a0Opm8M4gyGXp5eQ89zcx3KvDE84L_63s_4583R7WGcYhAHXyX1Q',
{title:'Level',height:'500',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',modal:true,dialog:null},
't-Dialog--standard',
$('#createLevel'));
```

I am just trying to change the P6010_TRACK_SERNO item from 90 to 95 as an example

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I usually set the value of the item not on button click, but on initializing the called page.

For example, you could copy the item value via PL/SQL in Pre-Rendering like this:

```
:P6010_TRACK_SERNO := :P0000_MASTER_ID;
```

Is that an option?